# MongoDB data integrity

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB, and the most difficult to understand is how to ensure data integrity.

I've got two collections Post -> Comment (One to many).

Is there a way to store number of comments for each post, without of using [two phase commit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/)?

```
Post {
    _id,
    text,
    commentsNumber
}

Comment {
    _id,
    text,
    postId
}
```

When comment is added / removed, `commentsNumber` have to be incremented / decremented. And this is two requests to two different collections. Such as in MongoDB a write operation is atomic on the level of a single document, there is a chance that comment will be added / removed, but commentsNumber won't be updated or vise versa.

What are the techniques to guarantee integrity?

- Run script every period of time to update `commentsNumber`?
- Not to store `commentsNumber` at all?

Comment: There are many ways, including embedding comments within the post itself. The "consistency" term is usually applied to data consistency across multiple instances when you use replication, so that reads of the same document from secondaries return same data. In your case "integrity" would be a better word choice.

Comment: @AlexBlex, embedding is not an option, because there could be too many comments, thanks for "integrity" term, updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is anything that can **guarantee** data integrity apart from the mentioned 2-phase commit. At least until [announced v4](https://www.mongodb.com/press/mongodb-announces-multi-document-acid-transactions-in-release-40).

There are few things to minimise chances of get wrong counts.
Combine insert and update into a single [bulk](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/). It will reduce chances that one of the operations fails on application side, since it is a single request.

Then check if `nInserted === 1`, and `nModified === 1`. Otherwise re-try or enqueue a re-calculation job for the given post id.

For re-tries it is essential to have [retryable writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/#retryable-writes) enabled, as you are going to use `$inc` on posts, which is quite far from idempotent operation.

Another option is to apply [transactionless](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Transactionless.html) approach - a kind of a combination of "Run script every period of time to update commentsNumber" and "Not to store commentsNumber at all". You will need to keep timestamps of the last re-calculation job, and count new comments since the date.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Didn't know about single bulk and transactionless aproach. It's very interesting to investigate.

Comment: Don't overestimate bulk operations. They help only on application level, i.e. there is no chance the app sends only one of 2 statements. It is still 2 writes on the db side, and it is possible one of them fail. You will need a hell of logic to handle such errors. Transactionless architecture is good, but is extremely expensive to run and evolve. Though if you have more than 16MB comments per post, you can probably afford it.

Comment: I don't have 16MB of comments, but most tutorials recommend to embed if it's 1:few relationship. And few is ~100. As I understood, it's used for been able to lazy load. If we have 10k comments, and need to load only 50 of them, we have to load all 10k on application side, if we embed.

Comment: It's not like "you have to load all 10k", but "it will load all 10k by default".  You still can exclude comments in `find` queries with projection, and you can load a slice of comments using aggregation framework. It is a bit more complex than regular `find`, but it is way-way-way less complex than dealing with data integrity problem you are concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned embedding comments within the Post is not a viable option for your use case and don't want to go with 2 phase commit,

I can think of below options:

1. Creating a secondary index on postId attribute of Comment collection. And finally using count(...) function based on postId on Comment collection.
2. The other option is to have a map-reduce job that stores the commentCount and postId in a new collection every time a Comment document is added.

In both the options you would not need to store commentNumbers in the Post document. One thing to note is, since the commentsCount is not part of Post document this would result in new query to mongo to read the count.

Comment: "every time a Post document is added", you mean Comment document? Can you please give reference using map-reduce job? I thought it's used only for read operations as custom aggregation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/)

Comment: It is a Typo and I meant when ever Comment document is added/removed. Regarding map-reduce, the link you posted is a good reference and shows how to aggregate the data based on cust_ID. Another link you could go through is http://thejackalofjavascript.com/mapreduce-in-mongodb/

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, I believe OP asked about example of how to employ map-reduce to "stores the commentCount and postId", as [one of the restrictions of the reducer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function) is *The reduce function should not access the database, even to perform read operations.*

Comment: Then option 2 is restricted?

Comment: @AlexBlex Not sure why we would need to read the data during the reduce function.But, is it because `we need to get the existing comment count so far for a post and increment count whenever comment gets added`? If so, I think we can use out with a reduce option ` `out: { reduce: "comment_count_stat" }`, that will merge the new result with the existing result by applying reduce function per [collection with action reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#output-to-a-collection-with-an-action) so that it is incremental. Or did I misunderstood the statement?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu `out` options allows to write into a single collection. I fail to see how map-reduce can be used to add a comment **and** increment comment's counter within a single request, not even mentioning atomic operation.

Comment: @AlexBlex It is not within a single request. The way I am looking at it is, once the new comment is inserted we could trigger (via custom triggering solution like opLog monitoring etc) or periodically invoke the map-reduce that will take care of increment the comment's counter.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, ah, that explains. The problem with this approach is number of actual comments and the counter will not match between inserting a comment and finishing the map-reduce job. It is basically the same *Run script every period of time to update commentsNumber* OP proposed in the question, isn't it?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, btw, there are [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) in v3.6. Should be a bit simpler than dealing with oplog directly.

Comment: @AlexBlex Yeah change streams would simplify data update notification scenarios.