# MongoDB query to fetch list of documents with count of external linked documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have a mongodb database with collection documents that are approximately as follows:

```js
// user document
{
    _id: $oid,
    name: "name",
    description: "description".
    // ...
}

// book document
{
    _id: $oid,
    userId: "..."
    name: "name",
    description: "description"
    // ...
}

// page document
{
    _id: $oid,
    bookId: "..."
    name: "name",
    description: "description"
    // ...
}
```

A user has many books and a book has many pages. The reason why each entity is a separate document is because a user can have thousands of books and a book can have thousands of pages, so, if everything was in a single document, we could reach the 16MB limit quite easily.

What is the best way to retrieve the list of books for a specified `userId` with a `pageCount` field for each book?

This is the json result I need.

```js
{
    books: [{
        _id: $oid,
        name: "name1",
        description: "description1",
        pageCount: 8
    }, {
        _id: $oid,
        name: "name2",
        description: "description2",
        pageCount: 12
    },
        // ...
    ]
}
```

With a SQL database that would be pretty straightforward with a join count, but with mongodb I can't see any easy solution apart from making separate queries to get the list of books and then get the number of pages for each book.

Comment: If books don't lose pages often it would make sense to pre-aggregate the `pageCount` into `book` document. Otherwise you need to do expensive [$lookup aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) each time.

Comment: @AlexBlex pre-aggregation is something I considered. Would that mean that I would have to update the `book` document every time a new `page` is added or an existing `page` is removed? I guess that would need to be done at application level in a non-transactional fashion.

Comment: Yep, you see the problem. Just answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176763/mongodb-data-integrity/49178140#49178140). You have options - complex writes, accidental discrepancy, slow reads (either with lookup or 2 separate queries). Which one to choose really depends on how critical data integrity is vs how slow the reads are.

Comment: @AlexBlex MongoDB v4 transaction support looks promising to implement pre-aggregation, when that's released.

Answer (score 2):

It does not answer the question directly, but rather gives some ideas regarding

> making separate queries to get the list of books and then get the number of pages for each book

part. It is not always a bad thing. Mongodb is quite efficient in simple queries, so I give you some numbers to consider performance of a single $lookup pipeline vs multiple queries, and encourage you to test your typical queries on your dataset. E.g.pagination can make a huge difference, if you don't need all the data at once.

### set up

A small database of 100 users X 1,000 books X 1,000 pages each on a tiny 1 vCPU / 2 GB Memory / 50 GB Disk / LON1 - Ubuntu MongoDB 3.4.10 on 16.04 droplet.

`pages` collection created as following:

```
for USERID in {1..100}; do   
    echo "" > pages.json;     
    for BOOKID in {1..1000}; do       
       ./node_modules/.bin/mgeneratejs "{\"bookId\": \"$USERID-$BOOKID\", \"name\": {\"\$sentence\":{\"words\":3}}, \"description\": \"\$paragraph\"}" -n 1000 >> pages.json
    done     
    cat pages.json | mongoimport -d so -c pages 
done
```

And the `books` one is pretty much the same.

The essential stats:

```
db.books.stats(1024*1024)
    "ns" : "so.books",
    "size" : 50,
    "count" : 100000,
    "avgObjSize" : 533,
    "storageSize" : 52,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "totalIndexSize" : 1,
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 0,
            "userId_1" : 0
    },

db.pages.stats(1024*1024)
    "ns" : "so.pages",
    "size" : 51673,
    "count" : 100000000,
    "avgObjSize" : 541,
    "storageSize" : 28920,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "totalIndexSize" : 1424,
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 994,
            "bookId_1" : 430
    },
```

### $lookup

The pipeline from @chridam's answer

```
db.books.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "userId": 18 } },
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "pages",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "bookId",
        "as": "pageCount"
    }},
    { "$addFields": {
        "pageCount": { "$size": "$pageCount" }
    }}
])
```

gives blazing fast response:

```
    "op" : "command",
    "command" : {
            "aggregate" : "books"
    },
    "keysExamined" : 1000,
    "docsExamined" : 1000,
    "nreturned" : 101,
    "responseLength" : 57234,
    "millis" : 1028
```

For the first 100 documents and let you start processing the documents within a second.

The overal time for the whole thing:

```
db.books.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "userId": 18 } },
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "pages",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "bookId",
        "as": "pageCount"
    }},
    { "$addFields": {
        "pageCount": { "$size": "$pageCount" }
    }}
]).toArray()
```

Adds another 8 seconds:

```
    "op" : "getmore",
    "query" : {
            "getMore" : NumberLong("32322423895"),
            "collection" : "books"
    },
    "keysExamined" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 0,
    "nreturned" : 899,
    "responseLength" : 500060,
    "millis" : 8471
```

**Total time to retrieve all data is more than 9 sec**

### multiple queries

1. retrieve books:

   ```
   let bookIds = []; 
   db.books.find({userId:12}).forEach(b=>{bookIds.push(b._id);});
   ```

   populates the array within 10 millis:

   ```
   "op" : "query",
   "query" : {
           "find" : "books",
           "filter" : {
                   "userId" : 34
           }
   },
   "keysExamined" : 101,
   "docsExamined" : 101,
   "nreturned" : 101,
   "responseLength" : 54710,
   "millis" : 3
   ```

   and

   ```
   "op" : "getmore",
   "query" : {
           "getMore" : NumberLong("34224552674"),
           "collection" : "books"
   },
   "keysExamined" : 899,
   "docsExamined" : 899,
   "nreturned" : 899,
   "responseLength" : 485698,
   "millis" : 7
   ```
2. count pages:

   ```
   db.pages.aggregate([
       { $match: { bookId: { $in: bookIds } } }, 
       { $group: { _id: "$bookId", cnt: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]).toArray()
   ```

   requires 1.5 seconds total:

   ```
   "op" : "command",
   "command" : {
           "aggregate" : "pages"
   },
   "keysExamined" : 1000001,
   "docsExamined" : 0,
   "nreturned" : 101,
   "responseLength" : 3899,
   "millis" : 1574
   ```

   and

   ```
   "op" : "getmore",
   "query" : {
           "getMore" : NumberLong("58311204806"),
           "collection" : "pages"
   },
   "keysExamined" : 0,
   "docsExamined" : 0,
   "nreturned" : 899,
   "responseLength" : 34935,
   "millis" : 0
   ```
3. merging results

   Not a query, yet should be done on application level. It takes few millis in mongoshell javascript, which makes **total time to retrieve all data less than 2 sec**.

Comment: Thanks, that is very interesting. Coming from a SQL background, making separate queries always sounds evil, but with Mongodb things are definitely different.

Answer (score 1):

With MongoDB's aggregation framework, there is a pipeline stage called **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** which allows you to do a a left outer join to another collection in the same database to filter in documents from the “joined” collection for processing.

Thus armed with this weapon, you can run an aggregate pipeline operation which joins the book collection to the pages collection.

Within the pipeline steps you can get the `pageCount` by querying the size of the results array from the "join".

Consider running the following aggregate operation to get the desired result, assuming your MongoDB server version is at least 3.4:

```
db.books.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "userId": userId } },
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "pages",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "bookId",
        "as": "pageCount"
    }},
    { "$addFields": {
        "pageCount": { "$size": "$pageCount" }
    }}
])
```

---

Alternatively, you can run the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** pipeline from the `users` collection as

```
db.user.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": userId } },
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "books",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "userId",
        "as": "books"
    }},
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "pages",
        "localField": "books._id",
        "foreignField": "bookId",
        "as": "pages"
    }},
    { "$addFields": {
        "books": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$books",
                "as": "book",
                "in": {
                    "name": "$$book.name",
                    "description": "$$book.description",
                    "pageCount": { "$size": "$$book.pages" }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Comment: Why not `db.books.aggregate`? It should save 1 lookup stage.

Comment: Still the same because you would need the user data

Comment: But why? *the best way to retrieve the list of books for a specified userId* doesn't require any user data to me.

Comment: Yes, user data is not required in the result. I am still curious about what the performance impact would be compared to making separate page queries at application level.

Comment: You are right, I misread that requirement. I have updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$lookup` stage from the aggregation framework :

```
db.Users.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: userId}},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "Book",
        localField: "userId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "book"
    }},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "Page",
        localField: "bookId",
        foreignField: "book._id",
        as: "page"
    }}
])
```

and add stage `$group` to calculate the number of pages. But I think this query will be pretty slow. And if you want to sharded your collection after, or if it already the case, you canno't use $lookup

Comment: Yes, that is something I considered, but my concern was about performance and future-proofing in case of sharded db. Thanks

Comment: In that case, the best solution is to do it with multiple queries. You can always test the performance of the query and see if it answer to your need but it will works only with unsharded collections so...